# Необходимо с помощью jQuery отобразить скрытый контент из элемента .hidden в другом элементе, но как это сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Отобразить скрытый контент из элемента .hidden в элементе .container-main вместо надписи - Please wait. Loading...

```
<div class="container-main">
        <p class="loading">Please wait. Loading...</p>
    </div>


<div class="hidden">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quam, voluptatum fuga aspernatur rerum magni! Aliquid vero, incidunt distinctio doloribus optio a repellendus qui doloremque eligendi, omnis minus! Molestiae, enim.</p>
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: не знаю с чего начать

Comment: ознакомьтесь с jquery selectors и методом http://jquery-docs.ru/manipulation/replacewith/ .

Comment: вот такой код нашел: $("p.loading").replaceWith(".hidden"); но он вместо всего блока показывает .hidden

Comment: Скорее $("p.loading").replaceWith($(".hidden")) , можете кстати и сами на свой вопрос ответить - сообществу на пользу, да и отмечать правильные ответы тоже было бы неплохо

Comment: а как отмечать? я бы с радостью:)

Comment: там вроде галочка слева возле количества голосов за вопрос

Comment: репутация не позволяет пока

Comment: http://puu.sh/j7fIe/bbe6908cc0.png раньше таких ограничений не было, ну значит желаю вам поднабрать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#butt').on('click', function() {

  $('.container-main').html(''); //очистили
  $('.hidden').appendTo('.container-main'); //перенесли
  $('.hidden').show(); //показали

  $(this).hide(); //кнопку убрали

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-main">
  <p class="loading">Please wait. Loading...</p>
</div>

<input type="submit" id="butt" value="Нажми меня">

<div class="hidden">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quam, voluptatum fuga aspernatur rerum magni! Aliquid vero, incidunt distinctio doloribus optio a repellendus qui doloremque eligendi, omnis minus! Molestiae, enim.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: все супер, но необходимо без кнопки, а просто при загрузке страницы

Comment: разобрался, оставил только:$('.container-main').html(''); //очистили
  $('.hidden').appendTo('.container-main'); //перенесли
  $('.hidden').show(); //показали

Comment: Разумеется. Кнопка там для демонстрации только. Если помогло - нажмите галочку "правильный ответ" слева-сверху от ответа. Спасибо.

Comment: И вам огромное спасибо.